# Insert contents of a .SVG file into an HTML element

Tags: jquery, html, dom, svg

I have an SVG element in a file `my_ui_element.svg`. I want to insert this SVG into an HTML element in `index.html`.  How can I do this?

**HTML before insert:**

```
<div class="Container">
  <!-- Insert SVG here -->
</div>
```

**HTML after insert:**

```
<div class="Container">
  <svg>...</svg>
</div>
```

**Note:** Using `<img src="my_ui_element.svg">` is not an acceptable answer since it does not add the SVG element to the DOM.

Comment: you write code. you already tagged the question with the EXACT method to accomplish it: DOM

Comment: @MarcB, you're right this is simple.  self posted the answer anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This turned out to be trivial. An SVG file is valid HTML.

Here is a jquery answer:

`$('.Container').load('my_ui_element.svg');`

Comment: This helped me much! Just wanted to point out for everyone passing by, that on Safari, the load seems to not always trigger a reflow / repaint of the DOM (or too early, before the file has finished loading). So the changes are invisible until another event causes a reflow / repaint.